# Coc.nvim suggestion box typing error with ^Z

Tags: vim, coc.nvim

First of all, I'm sorry for my poor english.
But I really want to solve this problem.

I'm `VIM` user in M1 Mac,
and I use `coc.nvim`

Problem :
`^Z` is force inserted when I continue typing with coc-suggestion box.
screenshot down below;

Before more typing:

[image: Before more typing]

After typing with suggestion box:

[image: After typing with suggestion box.]

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use CoC's official support channel.

Answer (score -1):

I added issue yesterday,
I got answer 2h ago.

It seems like this problem fixed.
Enjoy your vim life;

[issue and answer link](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/3702#event-6233130381)